# getting errors on PHP image upload

Tags: php

So I am trying to upload an image with PHP scripts but I am getting these errors
ps : file_uploads = On in php.ini

**File is an image - image/jpeg.
Warning: move_uploaded_file(image/promotions/verso.jpg): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in W:\xampp\htdocs\elkssar\functions\upload.php on line 43
Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move "W:\xampp\tmp\phpCB68.tmp" to "image/promotions/verso.jpg" in W:\xampp\htdocs\elkssar\functions\upload.php on line 43
Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.**

```
<?php
$target_dir = "image/promotions/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["upload"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: can your webserver write to the specified folder?

Comment: @Erik yeh for sure

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. The most likely reason that the file isn't where PHP says it is is because your web server doesn't have permission to put it there. I'd go and check again.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular the problem is I tried the code on a local server too (XAMPP) and the same errors again

Comment: ok guys thanks for the replays i found the problem it was a stupid mistake iam not in the same location as image/ so the code line should be like this
$target_dir = "../image/promotions/";

Answer (score 0):

it was a stupid mistake iam not in the same location as image/ so the code line should be like this `$target_dir = "../image/promotions/";`

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the following condition

```
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}
```

as you are doing AND condition check for the file formats and the file you are uploading will only have 1 format not all. So instead of doing AND try using OR

```
// Allow certain file formats
if(!in_array($imageFileType, ["jpg","png","jpeg","gif"]) ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
```